# Properly handle Azure MessagingCommunicationException?

Tags: azure

I've got several long-running processes that listen on the same azure servicebus topic.  After an extended time of running (usually a few days), I get one of these exceptions in one of the processes (and they all seem to stop working).  The message itself and the documentation suggest that the answer is to re-try the connection.  At first I was just trying to create a new TopicClient, but then found out the actual connection was held by the MessagingFactory.  I have now tried creating a whole new MessagingFactory as well, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

What is the proper way to handle this exception?  An example (even pseudocode) would be great.

Comment: Any luck with the answer I am having similar issues.

Comment: Probably a bit late...But the azure sdk has since added a more intuitive (imo) message-pump api.  See http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/introducing-the-event-driven-message-programming-model-for-the-windows-azure-service-bus/